# Angular ng-pattern regex code for US Zipcodes and Canadian Postal codes

Tags: regex, angularjs, zipcode, postal-code

I could anybody help me out?

I am looking for some regexp  to use to validate US Zip codes and Canadian Postal codes in AngularJS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
^(\d{5}(-\d{4})?|[A-Z]\d[A-Z] *\d[A-Z]\d)$
```

http://regex101.com/r/nO4zF5

Remove the `^` and `$` anchors if you don't want to match the start and end of the string.

When using in Javascript remember that you need to use the `/` delimiter:

```
if (/^(\d{5}(-\d{4})?|[A-Z]\d[A-Z] *\d[A-Z]\d)$/.test(str)) {
    // it's a match!
}
```

And directly, as an Angular `ng-pattern`:

```
ng-pattern="/^(\d{5}(-\d{4})?|[A-Z]\d[A-Z] *\d[A-Z]\d)$/"
```

Comment: I didn't realize I had to put slashes at the beginning and the end of the expression, I am all good now, thank you remus /^(\d{5}(-\d{4})?|[A-Z]\d[A-Z] *\d[A-Z]\d)$/

Comment: Yes, that's how you denote a regular expression in .js ;)

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice if the example was in the angular js context. I had to read the comments to figure it out. Would be helpful for other noobs like me.

Comment: Trouble with that Gene is that the other half of people will think that's part of the expression 